# Installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 - Does not show in boot priority (UEFI)

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, grub, troubleshooting

I'm sure most of you are tired of answering this question, believe me, I've perused the various threads pertaining to installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 and having boot issues. Anyways, humor me if you would, please.

My PC is fairly new (2014). It's an Acer laptop that came pre-installed with Windows 10. I'm a novice at this stuff. Never tried Ubuntu before and I'm loving it! The issue is that after installing Ubuntu (16.04), every reboot just goes straight into W10. No Grub or anything, just a normal startup.

I've gone into my UEFI and looked at the boot order, but Ubuntu is not listed. HOWEVER, I can load Ubuntu perfectly fine and run the environment with zero issues. I do this by simply holding Shift+clicking the "restart" option, thus giving me options to enter UEFI, load from LiveCD or LiveUSB, etc.

Choosing the option to load from another area (My screen shows the USB and CD, then Ubuntu), I can click on Ubuntu and the Grub will appear and I can load the OS without any hassle.

Before I go on, I must say that Linux is beautiful. Being a guy who has only ever encountered MS and Mac/iOS, I have to say this is a very sleek and easily understandable design.

Anyways back to the issue. As I understand it, there are various "fix-it" threads on here that lead you through various processes to try and solve this problem so that you can have Grub appear first and foremost.

I have gone into the Terminal on W10 and set the bootmgr to the path \BOOT\EFI\grubx64.efi if I recall correctly. Just as I'm writing this I've noticed another thing gone awry. So I will quickly explain this. Okay, first I installed Ubuntu alongside W10 with no issues (all UEFI). Then it reboots directly to W10. I read on a thread that you have to set a path for the bootmgr to what I had written [above]. Reboot. Booted straight to W10.

Then I figured maybe it was the BOOT.efi file I was supposed to set the path to, so I set it to that. Reboot. Booted straight to W10. Now I think the issue is something else. Moving to another "solution," it tells me I have to go into Ubuntu and change the boot priority through the terminal. Open term, sudo apt-get install efibootmgr. After that it said that everything was Kosher, no updates. Then I did efibootmgr and it listed everything INCLUDING Ubuntu, but going through my UEFI, Ubuntu is not there.

So, I changed the boot order through the term, -o 4,0,2,1 so that Ubuntu is first and W10 is second. Exited and then reboot. Booted straight to W10. Now that I look at my File Explorer on W10, The Ubuntu drive that was clearly visible right next to the C drive is gone. It doesn't show up anymore, which I think is weird. Maybe I did something, I don't know.

I don't think the issue is UEFI related because the install and both environments work seamlessly (Only installed Ubuntu once as UEFI and it worked just fine. Secure Boot is enabled. Only other option is Legacy Boot, which W10 is NOT. Also, Secure Boot and UEFI are only able to be enabled and disabled together, don't know if that makes a difference). I just can't seem to get Grub to show, or get Ubuntu to be the first in the boot priority.

If you need more information from me, please ask and give me directions on how to acquire what you seek. I'm still a novice (literally tried out Linux for the first time ever about 5 hours ago), but I can understand computer lingo and intermediate operations.

EDIT: Recently just tried this fix as well. http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/bootmenu Still, didn't work.

EDIT2: Turns out I just had to run the Boot Repair. I am facepalming so hard right now. 5 hours where I could have been more productive...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [Boot repair tool?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

It should be already installed on the disk else you can install it via commands

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

Had a simular problem this morning and this worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

At installation DO NOT SELECT the default USB drive option to boot from, SELECT the UEFI USB drive option to boot from and continue with the installation. It will detect the Ubuntu boot menu after installation.